# CALayer _layer is not getting initialized on application startup?! (OSX, Cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, avfoundation, quartz-core

I'm very new to AVFoundation and QuartzCore development and I'm having troubles with CALayers. I'm sorry if this is a silly problem.

Here's my code:

.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@interface Document : NSPersistentDocument 
{
    AVPlayer *player;
    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer;
    NSView *playerView;
}
@property AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer;
@property AVPlayer *player;
@property IBOutlet NSView *playerView;


@end
```

.m

```
#import "Document.h"

@implementation Document
@synthesize playerView;
@synthesize player;
@synthesize playerLayer;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {    
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)windowNibName
{
    return @"Document";
}

- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];
    [[aController window] setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];

    // HERE the layer is nill, and I don't understand why it's not getting initialized?! 
    [[[self playerView] layer] setBackgroundColor:CGColorGetConstantColor(kCGColorBlack)];
}

+ (BOOL)autosavesInPlace
{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Any kind of help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `layer` is nil, you should start by suspecting that its parent `playerView` is nil. Is it? If so, you probably haven't hooked up the outlet in the nib. (I see you have *declared* `playerView` as an outlet in your *code*, but that doesn't mean you've configured the *nib* correctly.)

Comment: the problem is...that the playerView isn't nil! I did, hook up my nib to the playerView. That's why it is a mystery for me :)

Comment: Did you turn on `wantsLayer` for this view? On Mac OS X you don't automatically get a layer the way you do on iOS... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html

Comment: nope...this one I didn't know...where should I do this?...actually it says: For views you create programmatically...But this view is not created programmatically, I set it up in the nib, right?!